# User login with phone auth code expired time check & change expired time Firebase Web v9

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm integrating Firebase Auth signInWithPhoneNumber into my React web app & I'm confused on how to go from:

1. submit phone #.
2. wait 5 mins but code is verified.
3. submit code verification.

I can successfully login with phone number, but my issue is that I change expiration time.

Here's the code:

```
const setUpRecaptha = (number) => {
    const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
        'size': 'invisible',
        'callback': (response) => console.log('callback', response),
        'expired-callback': () => { console.log('expire-call back')}
    }, auth);
    return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, recaptchaVerifier, { timeout: 120000 /* 2 minutes */ });
}
```

```
const getOtp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(number);
    setError("");
    if (number === "" || number === undefined)
        return setError("Please enter a valid phone number!");
    try {
        const response = await setUpRecaptha(number);
        setResult(response);
        setFlag(true);
    } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
    }
};
```

```
const verifyOtp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    if (otp === "" || otp === null) return;
    try {
        console.log('result', result)
        const response = await result.confirm(otp);
        console.log('response', response)
        // navigate("/home");
    } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
    }
};
```

```html
    <h2>Firebase Phone Auth</h2>
    {error && {error}}
            Cancel
            &nbsp;
            Send Otp

    <Form onSubmit={verifyOtp} style={{ display: flag ? "block" : "none" }}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicOtp">
            <Form.Control type="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP" onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)} />
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="button-right">
            <Link to="/">
                <Button variant="secondary">Cancel</Button>
            </Link>
            &nbsp;
            <Button type="submit" variant="primary">Verify</Button>
        </div>
    </Form>

    <div className="p-4 box mt-3 text-center">
        Don't have an account? <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
    </div>
</div>
```